# How do I query a collection of firebase documents by a properties value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, searchbar

I am a building a Firebase React social media app with a search bar, I want my searchbar to show suggestions of users based on the value of input. If I type "F" I expect Foo and then underneath Bar, pretty much like any social media search bar that filters the users and returns the relevant ones. . I am having trouble understanding the Firebase queries and what would be appropriate for this.

The Layout of the DB is
users collections
documents that represent a user
a username property on the document

```
  const searchUser = async (text) => {
 
    const queryUsers = [];
    if (text !== '') {
 
      try {
        const usersRef = collection(firestore, "users");
 
        const q = query(usersRef, orderBy("username"),startAt(text.toLowerCase()),limit(5))
 
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)
 
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          queryUsers.push(doc.data())
 
        })
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
 
    }
  console.log(queryUsers);
  return queryUsers;
  };
```

I tried all sorts of queries but none of them worked, I am expecting to get all the users ordered by the value of the string that was sent to the query

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, the username was saved with a Capital letter. Not sure if this query is also the best one.